# Getting error "Database is locked" when I trye to save data i SQLITE DB

Tags: sqlite

I have following class that connects to database but when I trye to call the method that saves data I get error "Database is locked". Could some one please help me to find the problem?

```
class Data
{
    private SQLiteConnection con;
    private void ConnectoDB()
    {
        String PathDB = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        PathDB += "\\SQLiteDB_MEDFit.db";
        string cs = @"URI=file:" + PathDB;
        string stm = "SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()";
        con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con);
        string version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    }


    public Boolean SaveToDatabase(string name, string number)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            ConnectoDB();
           con.Execute("insert into People(name, number) values ('" + name+ "', '" + number+ "')");
           
            con.Close();

            result = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
```

}
}

The code that calls the "SaveToDatabase()"

```
string name = textBox1.Text(); 
string number = textBox2.Text(); 
Data connect = new Data(); 
connect.SavetoDB(name, number);
```

Comment: You got the db open in another application? That's usually what it means..

Comment: No. Thats the only application and code to access to database.

Comment: Please show the code that is calling SaveToDatabase().

Comment: The code thats calling SaveToDatabase() is this:

Comment: string name = textBox1.Text();
           
 string number = textBox2.Text();

           
 Data connect = new Data();
            
connect.SavetoDB(name, number);